# Can I appear as if I were in a Schengen country if I enter/exit without passport stamps?

Tags: schengen, residence-permits

I have a resident permit of Schengen country X.

I entered Schengen directly from X with stamp from X.

I take a bus to another Schengen country and leave Schengen from there without a stamp.

I come back to X from a Schengen country that doesn't stamp.

There are no other stamps on the passport for that period.

Will X know I was not in the country? They would know if they really want to know but I'm talking about normal circumstances. Asking for residence permit renewal and citizenship application.

Comment: The only reason to want to know if a country knows something or not is to know whether it is safe to lie about that or not. And we don't advise people how to break laws and regulations by lying, or at least not in general (there have been a few questions about hiding one trip from one country for very specific country pairs where it is not illegal or against regulations to hide that trip.) If you're planning to say you were in X for longer than you were, don't do that.

Comment: No, it is automatic. I don't need to say anything. They might ask for proof of stay but that's irrelevant to this post. So, please stay on the topic.

Comment: When you apply for renewal or citizenship you're expected to truthfully report your travel history. What does it matter to you in this situation whether the country X already knows what you're reporting? You're still required to report it.

Comment: The procedure differs by country or even its subdivisions (e.g. different Swiss cantons or different Ausländerbehörden in German states). In general, most governments impose the burden of proof on an applicant to justify their claims.

Comment: Like I said earlier, there's no reporting requirement. If they don't think you met the conditions (aka your profile seems weird), then and ONLY THEN burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @xngtng In Germany, the **residence law** (AufentG) is now a federal law - so the rules are the same.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the law is the same but the attitudes and working processes however differs, as are required documents (or rather required form of documents) as many foreigners in Germany can attest. Some offices may be more likely to ask for justifications than others.

Answer (score 3):

Assume 'they' don't want to know exactly when **residents** leave and enter and for how long.

This will not change when the **Entry/Exit System (EES)** comes into force, after which there will be no more passports stamps.

Article 2(3) of REGULATION (EU) 2017/2226 excludes residents who have a **residence permit** card or a **residence card** with them when leaving or entering.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused by your point. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @kamksmdkasdm Since they do not collect information when **residents** leave or enter, they are not interested. They are only interested in **visitors**, which is why you must show (with the **residence permit** card or a **residence card**) that you are **not** a visitor.

Comment: So is that a yes or no? Can I appear as I am in Schengen country if I enter/exit without passport stamps?

Comment: @kamksmdkasdm you say "they would know if they really want to know but I'm talking about normal circumstances" but we don't know how strong their desire is, so to speak, under normal circumstances.  Mark Johnson's answer notes that they normally don't track entries and exits for people with residence permits, so the ruse with the bus isn't going to affect their records of your presence one way or the other (i.e. if your permit is from Austria it doesn't matter whether you're crossing the external border there or in Spain, and internal travel is tracked even less).

Comment: @kamksmdkasdm But we don't know whether they look at other data in assessing the veracity of any statements you might make concerning your presence or to assess your travel history regardless of whether you've made any statements.  They could be looking at all sorts of things, and they might not be looking at any of them.  We just don't know, and it's probably not possible to find out definitively.

Comment: @kamksmdkasdm Sorry, but I am not sure what you mean with 'Can I appear as I am in Schengen country'. You may travel, as a resident of one Schengen country, to other Schengen countries with your passport **and** residence permit card and they do not care if there are no stamps in your passport.

Comment: @Mark Are you human?

Comment: @kamksmdkasdm “Can I appear as I am in Schengen country” is grammatically incorrect and therefore makes no sense. Do you mean “Can I appear *as if I were* in a Schengen country”?

Comment: Ok my bad, you're right